# Is it legal to initialize a struct with only one array as member using a initializer list directly?

Tags: c++, syntax, initializer-list

```
#include <iostream>

class vec
{
public:
    int  arr[2];
};


int main()
{
    vec a = { { 1,2 } };// works 
    vec b = { 1,2 };// works too ,but why ?
    std::cin.get();
}
```

vec has no constructor other than the default constructor .

But this piece of code compiles ,I wonder why .

http://ideone.com/uyx98o

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Comment: This is how `std::array` works too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) is amazing, you don't even have to get the nesting right to make it work, and you can also provide less values than there are members:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A {
    struct { int a; std::string b[3]; } a;
    double b, c;
};

int main() {
    A a = { 10, "a", "b", "c", 3.1415 };
    std::cout << a.a.a << " " << a.a.b[0] << " " << a.a.b[2]
              << " " << a.b << " " << a.c;
}
```

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98f21aa0aa3e5069)